# How to programmatically confirm a user in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am writing a script that automatically imports users into magento.
Here is a code snippet:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->website_id = $websiteId; 
$customer->setStore($store);

$customer->loadByEmail($riga[10]);

echo "Importo ".$data[0]."\n";
echo "  email :".$data[10]."\n";

$customer->setTaxvat($data[7]);
$customer->lastname =    $lastname;
$customer->email =       $data[10]; 
$customer->password_hash = md5($data[0]);

$customer->save();
```

The problem is that the users are created as "not confirmed", while I would like them to be "confirmed".

I tried with:

```
$customer->setConfirmation('1');
```

before the save, but it didn't work. Does anybody know how to confirm the user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think `setConfirmation()` is waiting for a confirmation key. Try passing `null` and I think it will work?

Just to clarify:

```
$customer->save();
$customer->setConfirmation(null);
$customer->save();
```

Should force confirmation.

Comment: That made it. :-)
I'd just like to highlight that when creating a customer it is important to save *before* and *after* setting the confirmation key, as melee pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

When I created accounts, they were already confirmed, but they were disabled! This fixed it:

```
$customer->save();
$customer->setConfirmation(null);
$customer->setStatus(1);
$customer->save();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Nicely answered, though it's worth reading existing answers to see if the problem has already been solved in a similar way.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a "status" property on customer, so setStatus(1) is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Saving the entire model is expensive. You can save only the confirmation attribute which is very fast:

```
$customer->setConfirmation(NULL);
$customer->getResource()->saveAttribute($customer, 'confirmation');
```